# SQL select count and sum from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help to resolve this.
I have 4 tables :

### Transactions

```
| id | cid | gt |   rt |

|  1 |  6  | 2  |  5   |
|  2 |  6  | 9  |  7.5 |
|  3 |  6  | 3  |  9.7 |
|  4 |  3  | 3  |  7.0 |
|  5 |  3  | 7  |  6.8 |
|  6 |  9  | 4  |  2.5 |
|  7 |  9  | 2  |  5.4 |
```

### Clients

```
| id | firstname | lastname | date |

|  1 |  jean     | moulin   | 1987 | 
|  2 |  salah    | fera     | 1968
|  3 |  marouan  | youra    | 2001 |
|  4 |  amin     | esa      | 1963 |
|  5 |  kamal    | tara     | 1789 |
|  6 |  moad     | mara     | 2005 |
|  9 |  safaa    | dara     | 2004 |
```

### Produit A

```
| id | cid | 

|  1 |  6  | 
|  2 |  6  | 
|  3 |  3  | 
|  4 |  3  | 
|  5 |  3  |
|  6 |  4  | 
|  7 |  1  |
```

### Produit B

```
| id | cid |

|  1 |  6  | 
|  2 |  3  | 
|  3 |  9  | 
|  4 |  3  | 
|  5 |  3  | 
|  6 |  4  | 
|  7 |  6  |
```

The result that i need is :

```
cid |  name |  date  |  pa | pb | gt | rt | 
3   |       |        |     |    |    |    |
6   |       |        |     |    |    |    |
9   |       |        |     |    |    |    |
```

I need to select from transaction all distinct client id (pid) and select the firstname and last name (name = firstname lastname) and date from clients table and sum all values (gt) and (rt) and search in table produitA the number of products for this client by his id and the same thing for the table produitB.

What i do for this but it don't work is (suggested by Gimeniux):

```
SELECT 
clients.id, 
CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as name,
date, 
count(distinct produitA.id) as pa, 
count(distinct produitB.id) as pb, 
sum(gt) AS gt, 
sum(rt) AS rt 

FROM clients
LEFT JOIN transactions ON clients.id = transactions.pid
LEFT JOIN produitA ON clients.id  = produitA.cid
LEFT JOIN produitB ON clients.id = produitB.cid

where pid is not null
group by clients.id
```

The probleme here is that gt and rt values are true for only the first client. For the second client and third and ... there is different values that are not true.

Comment: In your transaction table how you know if `pid` is productA or productB?

Comment: Sorry you description isnt clear describe what are those fields? is `cid` `client_id`? What is your desire output?

Comment: this doesnt make sense. You join clients using `ON clients.id transactions.pid` and also join products using `transactions.pid` I think you need a column `client_id` for your transaction table

Comment: pid is the cid : client_id i will update the post now

Answer (score 1):

Although is hard for me to see the logic between your tables, you can use this query to get the result you desire. But i think it won't work if there are two same 'gt' or two same 'rt' values for one client.

```
SELECT 
clients.id, 
CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as name,
date, 
count(distinct produitA.id) as pa, 
count(distinct produitB.id) as pb, 
sum(distinct gt) AS gt, 
sum(distinct rt) AS rt 

FROM clients
LEFT JOIN transactions ON clients.id = transactions.pid
LEFT JOIN produitA ON clients.id  = produitA.cid
LEFT JOIN produitB ON clients.id = produitB.cid

where pid is not null

group by clients.id
```

Row for pid=9 doesn't show because in the data you gave there is no client with id=9

Comment: Thank you so much for answer.. gt and rt values can be the same for the same client. gt is his income. So he can earn 5 dolars now and 5 tomorow. I thint it work if i put sum(gt) inside of sum(distinct gt) ?

Comment: Not working if i want sum all gt and rt values and not only distinct values